# MySQL/PHP how to get specific field id from field which is related with another field of the same row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've two tables:

**Database**

[image]

'intervaloHorario' has many 'citas'

**Citas** (idCitas, idIntervaloHorario, cita)

**IntervalosHorarios** (idIntervaloHorario, intervaloHorario)

In the table:

[image: table]

I want to get 'intervaloHorario' which is related with its own 'cita' dynamically. I'm trying this by passing the current id of cita.
I don't know if you understand what I intend.

**Model**

```
public function get_idintervalo($idCitas) {

        $query = $this->db->query('select intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario '
            . 'from intervaloshorarios left join citas '
            . 'on intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario=citas.idCitas '
            . 'where citas.idCitas =  '.$idCarga.' ;');


        return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function entregas_lista($idCitas) {

  $crud->where('entregas.idCitas =', $idCitas); 
//Esta es la función que llama a la consulta del modelo   
$query = $this->Intervalos_Model->get_idintervalo($idCitas);

 if ($crud->getState() == "add") {
            $crud->change_field_type('idCitas', 'hidden', $idCitas);
            $crud->change_field_type('idIntervaloHorario', 'hidden', $query);
        }


}
```

Error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion
```

This query gives me no errors but it isn't letting me to save the form, so I think the query is wrong. How can I make it work?

Comment: "This query gives me no errors but it isn't letting me to save the form, so i think the query is wrong" Codeignitor gives a error when there is a SQL error....

Comment: Yes but in my case, the error comes when i'm trying to save the form. I think the id is not corresponding with its element of join table

Comment: Is the function get_idintervalo in your model correct? Because you just return the SQL Command and you don't query anywhere!

Comment: You're right i have fixed that, i'll update the question. with this fix it throws the next error. (above)

Comment: And which line is actually producing the error?

Comment: Line Number: 2344  from GC library... I'll update my database too

Answer (score 0):

It's little hard to understand the comment which you have writen in you controller in your native language.

This are some basic change i would like to pointint out and I am also adding the solution hope it works.

First Use Model for database Querys, I see you have tryed something `->where` in controller.
Seondely, Your Error Clearly Says that you are passing an array in the query so chack that first.
I am adding a Join query which join `Citas` & `IntervalosHorarios` using `idIntervaloHorario` column where `idCitas`. 
I am assuming that `$idCarga = array('idCarga'=>'value idCarga value');`

```
$query = $this->db->selct('intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario')
        ->from('intervaloshorarios')
        ->join('citas', 'intervaloshorarios.idIntervaloHorario = citas.idIntervaloHorario', 'left outer')
        ->where('citas.idCitas',$idCarga['idCarga']);
        ->get();

 return $query->result();
```